# Finding the closest pair of points divide-and-conquer speed improvement

Tags: python, recursion, computational-geometry, divide-and-conquer

This is a follow up to a previously asked [Finding the closest pair of points divide-and-conquer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/198471/finding-the-closest-pair-of-points-divide-and-conquer/199668#199668) question . The original code changed significantly based on answers from @AJNeufeld therefore I created a new question per codereview guidelines for additional help.

After incorporating suggestions from answers to the original question linked above, the run-time improved by 30% which is significant. Nevertheless, the code is still slow and I think there is room for further improvements. My hunch is that `find_min_distance_in_rec` is slowing the code down. Below is the current code. Again, the code has been stress tested so I am confident that it's correct, however, it's slow.

```
#Uses python3
import math
import statistics as stats

# helper functions:
def two_point_distance(p0,p1):
    # returns distance between two (x,y) pairs
    return math.sqrt( ((p0[0]-p1[0])*(p0[0]-p1[0])) + 
                     ((p0[1] - p1[1])*(p0[1] - p1[1])) )

def combine_xy(x_arr,y_arr):
    # combine x_arr and y_arr to combined list of (x,y) tuples 
    return list(zip(x_arr,y_arr))

def find_closest_distance_brute(xy_arr):
    # brute force approach to find closest distance 
    dmin = math.inf
    for i, pnt_i in enumerate(xy_arr[:-1]):      
        dis_storage_min = min( two_point_distance(pnt_i, pnt_j) for pnt_j in xy_arr[i+1:])      
        if dis_storage_min < dmin:
            dmin = dis_storage_min  
    return dmin

def calc_median_x(xy_arr):
    # return median of x values in list of (x,y) points
    return stats.median( val[0] for val in xy_arr )

def filter_set(xy_arr_y_sorted, median, distance):
# filter initial set such than |x-median|<= distance
    return [ val for val in xy_arr_y_sorted if abs(val[0] - median) <= distance ]

def x_sort(xy_arr):
    # sort array according to x value
    return sorted(xy_arr, key=lambda val: val[0])

def y_sort(xy_arr):
    # sort array according to y value
    return sorted(xy_arr, key=lambda val: val[1])


def split_array(arr_x_sorted, arr_y_sorted,median):
    # split array of size n to two arrays of n/2
    # input is the same array twice, one sorted wrt x, the other wrt y
    leq_arr_x_sorted = [ val for val in arr_x_sorted if val[0] < median ]
    geq_arr_x_sorted = [ val for val in arr_x_sorted if val[0] > median ]
    eq_arr_x        = [ val for val in arr_x_sorted if val[0] == median ]

    n = len(eq_arr_x)//2
    leq_arr_x_sorted = leq_arr_x_sorted + eq_arr_x[:n]
    geq_arr_x_sorted = eq_arr_x[n:] + geq_arr_x_sorted

    leq_arr_y_sorted = [ val for val in arr_y_sorted if val[0] < median ]
    geq_arr_y_sorted = [ val for val in arr_y_sorted if val[0] > median ]
    eq_arr_y        = [ val for val in arr_y_sorted if val[0] == median ]

    n = len(eq_arr_y)//2
    leq_arr_y_sorted = leq_arr_y_sorted + eq_arr_y[:n]
    geq_arr_y_sorted = eq_arr_y[n:] + geq_arr_y_sorted

    return leq_arr_x_sorted, leq_arr_y_sorted, geq_arr_x_sorted, geq_arr_y_sorted

def find_min_distance_in_rec(xy_arr_y_sorted,dmin):
    # takes in array sorted in y, and minimum distance of n/2 halves
    # for each point it computes distance to 7 subsequent points
    # output min distance encountered

    dmin_rec = dmin

    if len(xy_arr_y_sorted) == 1:
        return math.inf

    if len(xy_arr_y_sorted) > 7:            
        for i, pnt_i in enumerate(xy_arr_y_sorted[:-7]):
            dis_storage_min = min(two_point_distance(pnt_i, pnt_j) 
                                 for pnt_j in xy_arr_y_sorted[i+1:i+1+7])
            if dis_storage_min < dmin_rec:
                dmin_rec = dis_storage_min

        dis_storage_min = find_closest_distance_brute(xy_arr_y_sorted[-7:])
        if dis_storage_min < dmin_rec:
            dmin_rec = dis_storage_min
    else:
        for k, pnt_k in enumerate(xy_arr_y_sorted[:-1]):      
            dis_storage_min = min( two_point_distance(pnt_k, pnt_l) 
                                for pnt_l in xy_arr_y_sorted[k+1:])      
            if dis_storage_min < dmin_rec:
                dmin_rec = dis_storage_min 

    return dmin_rec             

def find_closest_distance_recur(xy_arr_x_sorted, xy_arr_y_sorted):
    # recursive function to find closest distance between points
    if len(xy_arr_x_sorted) <=3 :
        return find_closest_distance_brute(xy_arr_x_sorted)

    median = calc_median_x(xy_arr_x_sorted)
    leq_arr_x_sorted, leq_arr_y_sorted , grt_arr_x_sorted, grt_arr_y_sorted = split_array(xy_arr_x_sorted, xy_arr_y_sorted, median)

    distance_left = find_closest_distance_recur(leq_arr_x_sorted, leq_arr_y_sorted)
    distance_right = find_closest_distance_recur(grt_arr_x_sorted, grt_arr_y_sorted)
    distance_min = min(distance_left, distance_right)

    filt_out = filter_set(xy_arr_y_sorted, median, distance_min)
    distance_filt = find_min_distance_in_rec(filt_out, distance_min)

    return min(distance_min, distance_filt)

def find_closest_point(x_arr, y_arr):
    # input is x,y points in two arrays, all x's in x_arr, all y's in y_arr
    xy_arr = combine_xy(x_arr,y_arr)
    xy_arr_x_sorted = x_sort(xy_arr)
    xy_arr_y_sored = y_sort(xy_arr)

    min_distance = find_closest_distance_recur(xy_arr_x_sorted, xy_arr_y_sored)

    return min_distance
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess I didn't make this clear in my answer on the original question.

The minimum of the square-root of the square distances is the square-root of the minimum of the square distances.  You can save time by calculating the square-root only when needed.

Replace this (and all calls to it):

```
def two_point_distance(p0,p1):
    # returns distance between two (x,y) pairs
    return math.sqrt( ((p0[0]-p1[0])*(p0[0]-p1[0])) + 
                     ((p0[1] - p1[1])*(p0[1] - p1[1])) )
```

with this:

```
def square_distance(p0, p1):
    dx = p0[0] - p1[0]
    dy = p0[1] - p1[1]
    return dx * dx  +  dy * dy
```

For example, `find_closest_distance_brute()` becomes:

```
def find_closest_distance_brute(xy_arr):
    # brute force approach to find closest distance
    dist_sqr_min = math.inf
    for i, pnt_i in enumerate(xy_arr[:-1]):      
        d_sqr_min = min( square_distance(pnt_i, pnt_j) for pnt_j in xy_arr[i+1:])      
        if d_sqr_min < dist_sqr_min:
            dist_sqr_min = d_sqr_min

    return math.sqrt(dist_sqr_min)   # Only calculate square-root of final value
```

Or more pythonically:

```
def find_closest_distance_brute(xy_arr):
    # brute force approach to find closest distance
    dist_sqr_min = min((square_distance(pnt_i, pnt_j) for i, pnt_i in enumerate(xy_arr[:-1])
                                                      for pnt_j in xy_arr[i+1:]),
                       default=math.inf)
    return math.sqrt(dist_sqr_min)   # Only calculate square-root of final value
```

---

Regarding `find_min_distance_in_rect()`:

```
def find_min_distance_in_rec(xy_arr_y_sorted,dmin):

    dmin_rec = dmin

    if len(xy_arr_y_sorted) == 1:
        return math.inf
```

What happens if `len(xy_arr_y_sorted) == 0`?  A better test would be `<= 1`.

```
if len(xy_arr_y_sorted) > 7:            
    # ... complicated code involving lots of 7's.
else:
    for k, pnt_k in enumerate(xy_arr_y_sorted[:-1]):      
        dis_storage_min = min( two_point_distance(pnt_k, pnt_l) 
                            for pnt_l in xy_arr_y_sorted[k+1:])      
        if dis_storage_min < dmin_rec:
            dmin_rec = dis_storage_min
```

This `else:` code looks exactly like `find_closest_distance_brute()` code.  In fact, you can replace it with a call to that function.

```
if len(xy_arr_y_sorted) > 7:            
    # ... complicated code involving lots of 7's.
else:
    dmin_rec = find_closest_distance_brute(xy_arr_y_sorted)
```

---

I don't like `# ... complicated code involving lots of 7's.`.  I'll rework it in a later edit.

---

See Peter Taylor's [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/199668) ... especially the part about `median = calc_median_x(xy_arr_x_sorted)`, for an O(n) to O(1) improvement.

---

As pointed out a second time by Peter Taylor, your code has a bug; `xy_arr_x_sorted` and `xy_arr_y_sorted` are supposed to have the same content, but due to the bug, may not.  He has suggested a change to fix the bug.  I have a different approach: eliminate `xy_arr_x_sorted` entirely.

In `find_closest_distance_recur()`, you have:

```
    if len(xy_arr_x_sorted) <=3 :
        return find_closest_distance_brute(xy_arr_x_sorted)
```

Since the arrays are supposed to contain the same content, you could replace this with:

```
    if len(xy_arr_y_sorted) <= 3:
        return find_closest_distance_brute(xy_arr_y_sorted)
```

Once you do that, you no longer have any useful references to the `[1]` members of the contents of `xy_arr_x_sorted`.  Instead, you could replace it with a sorted list of just the x-coordinates.

Once that is done, the partitioning code should be revisited.  There is no difference between duplicate median values, so a simple slice operation can divide the x-coordinate list in two with zero copying required.

Answer (score 2):

> The original code changed significantly based on answers

I think that the plural is inappropriate there: the changes seem to be solely based on AJNeufeld's answer. Not a single one of the issues [I pointed out](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/199668/1402) has been addressed, not even the bug:

> 1. My understanding is that the end result should be four arrays such that `leq_arr_x_sorted` and `leq_arr_y_sorted` contain the same points
>      sorted on different projections. But the `dmy_x` / `dmy_y` separation
>      of points whose `x` coordinate is `median` doesn't seem to guarantee
>      that those points will be sent to the same half in the `x`-projection
>      and the `y`-projection. In order to guarantee that an additional
>      pre-condition is needed: most obviously that in `arr_x_sorted` ties
>      are broken by `y`; but that pre-condition is not produced by `x_sort`.

This bug can be demonstrated easily by adding

```
    print(leq_arr_x_sorted, leq_arr_y_sorted, geq_arr_x_sorted, geq_arr_y_sorted)
```

before the `return` of `split_array` and calling with the simple test case `find_closest_point([1, 2, 2, 3], [4, 3, 2, 1])`.

Comment: I edited the question to give credit to AJNeufeld, thanks for the suggestion. Regarding your points for improvement, I commented on your answer under [original question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/198471/finding-the-closest-pair-of-points-divide-and-conquer/199668#199668)